# Replace certain values by the means of a table with replacement values

Tags: sql, dynamic, replace, sql-server-2012

I have a table with data in it. Generally the values are correct but sometimes we need to modify them. The modifications are saved in a second table.

I wanted to create a query that dynamically replaces the values if they exist in the replacement table.

This is what my query design looks like but it doesn't work:
[image: query design]

This is my query code:

```
SELECT
  b.Pos,
  b.Posten,
  IsNull(c.Wert_Neu, b.Bez1) AS Bez1,
  IsNull(c.Wert_Neu, b.Bez2) AS Bez2,
  IsNull(c.Wert_Neu, b.Bez3) AS Bez3,
  b.Wert,
  b.Einheit
FROM
  Table_Values b LEFT JOIN
  Table_Replacements c ON b.Bez1 = c.Wert_Alt AND b.Bez2 = c.Wert_Alt AND b.Bez3 = c.Wert_Alt
```

Where is my logical error? It doesn't replace the values. I assume it has something to do with the joins all going there without OR, but OR would be too costly for performance.

Anyone with a better idea?

Comment: First what RDBMS are you using? Second that is a `SELECT` you need and `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: If you have an `UPDATE` show us the code. If you need help writing the `UPDATE` we need know what is the RDBMS to write it.

Comment: Also you dont say what you want to save or if you want replace. Because if you want save old values like a log, you need include ID and DATE on the `C table`. Also write a trigger for `B table`

Comment: I think he means to replace them as he is selecting the data, not actually replace them in the table, just in the query results.

Comment: Exactly, I am just trying to replace them on the fly not entirely in the table. MSSQL 2012, added it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like what you want to do is to replace each of the values with the one that appears in the replacement table, but you have three separate columns, and each of those three values will have a different corresponding entry in the replacement table.  So you will have to link to that table three different times, once for each value, to link to its replacement, something like:

```
SELECT
  b.Pos,
  b.Posten,
  IsNull(c.Wert_Neu, b.Bez1) AS Bez1,
  IsNull(d.Wert_Neu, b.Bez2) AS Bez2,
  IsNull(e.Wert_Neu, b.Bez3) AS Bez3,
  b.Wert,
  b.Einheit
FROM
  Table_Values b 
  LEFT JOIN Table_Replacements c on b.bez1=c.wert_alt
  LEFT JOIN Table_Replacements d on b.bez2=d.wert_alt
  LEFT JOIN Table_Replacements e on b.bez3=e.wert_alt
```

It will be important that your replacement table have an index on wert_alt so that those links can be done efficiently.

Another possibility is to actually store the replacement values in your main data table.  So the fields in it would be:

```
bez1
bez1Replacement
bez2
bez2Replacement
...
```

Maybe have a trigger on the table so that on any insert or update, the trigger looks up each of the three replacement values from the replacement table and adds them to the main data record.  That would not be exactly normalized, but it would speed up your query.  But, you may not need to do that at all.  The above query is probably efficient enough if you do have that index.

Comment: Sorry, i had a significant mistake in my last paragraph that I just corrected.

Comment: Two things: thank you very much, works perfect with one change: remove the `,` after the joins at least that was a problem for me.

The replacement table is actually a temp table, created this way:
`CREATE TABLE #Table_Replacements (Wert_Neu nvarchar(255), Wert_Alt nvarchar(255));`

Comment: With a temp table, you are probably talking about something small enough that the db server will be able to keep it in memory anyway, so then you would not need the index.  Glad it worked.

Comment: Yes, the table would have 10 rows max. Thanks for your help, appreciate it!